# "Material doesn't have a ... property" when using more than 3 2D Textures

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I wrote multiple `fixed function Shaders`. I noticed that as soon as the Shader contains more than 3 2D Textures, the Shader breaks and unity reporty the `Material doesn't have a ... property` for every property... the material has. For example:

```
Shader "Custom/JustAnotherShader" {
    Properties{
        _MainTex("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" { }
        _TexA("Another Texture", 2D) = "black" { }
        _TexB("Yet Another Texture", 2D) = "" { }
        _TexC("One More Another Texture", 2D) = "" { }
    }

    SubShader {
        Pass {
            SetTexture[_MainTex] { combine texture }
            SetTexture[_TexA] { combine texture * previous }
            SetTexture[_TexB] { combine texture + previous }
            SetTexture[_TexC] { combine texture - previous }
        }
    }

    Fallback Off
}
```

This code would report this error for `_MainTex`, `_TexA`, `_TexB` and `_TexC`. This seems to be a bug. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having done some research, I can now come to the conclusion that more than three Textures are not supported for the shader compilation target I am using. (Unfortunately, I lost the link to the documentation that describes this limitation.)